# Can't access the variable which stores JSON data

Tags: javascript, json

When I try to acess actual_JSON variable through console on chrome I get "actual_JSON not declared". I'm new to jQuery. please help me out

```
function loadJSON(callback) {   
  var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
  xobj.open('GET', 'my_data.json', true); 
  xobj.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
      callback(xobj.responseText);
    }
  };
  xobj.send(null); 
}

function init() {
  loadJSON(function(response) {
    var actual_JSON = JSON.parse(response);
    console.log(actual_JSON);
  });
}

console.log(actual_JSON);
```

Comment: Where have you used `console.log(actual_JSON)`? The `actual_JSON` variable will only be within the scope of the anonymous callback function you provide to `loadJSON()`

Comment: `actual_JSON` is function-scoped, as opposed to global. That's fine, but it also means it is undefined outside of the context of the function, which explains why you can't read it from the developper console. You might want to set a breakpoint in the function so that you can inspect its scope when it is executed and check the value of the variable.

Comment: @Khacho remove the `console.log` at the end of the code block above. The first one will be working

Comment: I get undefined

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan It's not working

Comment: Please give more information than 'it doesn't work'. What does happen? Have you checked the console to ensure that the AJAX request succeeds? What data is returned, if any?

Comment: Which of the `console.log()` displays `undefined`? You've got two of them in your code. If there's only one log, it's the second one and it's because it has no access to the scope of the callback function. That would also mean that your callback is never executed (or raise an error before reaching the `console.log` call)

Comment: I removed the last `console.log` and made actual_JSON a global variable, now I'm getting this error on chrome  `Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.`

Comment: You really shouldn't make it global-scoped though, even if it solves your immediate problem. Anyway now you know your actual problem, which is that your request doesn't respect cross-origin constraints.

Comment: How do I solve cross-origin Constaints? any links? thanks

Comment: I'm not really knowledgeable on the subject, but I guess your XmlHttpRequest is malformed, since the message you got complains that the protocol used (which should be http/https) isn't accepted.

Answer (score 0):

i will do it like this,

```
function loadJSON(callback) {   
  var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
  xobj.open('GET', 'my_data.json', true); 
  xobj.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
      var myArr = JSON.parse(xobj.responseText);
        arrayfunction(myArr);
    }
  };
  xobj.send(null); 
 }
}
function arrayfunction(arr){

   var out = "";
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        out += arr[i].node+"\n";
    }
     console.log(out);
}
```

Where 'node' is a node for the json, so change that

Comment: you can disable same origin policy, but this is for development enviroment not for prodution or you can try mounting you app into a server enviroment as apache in your local host, i have never had issues in the apache server